# Ureadahead errors

Tags: ureadahead

How to prevent `ureadahead` from trying to read 
non-existent ***logs*** from home folder.
`journalctl -u ureadahead.service` give errors like these below:

> ```
> ureadahead:/home/$USER/.cache/upstart/gnome-keyring.log: There is no such file or folder  
> ureadahead:/home/$USER/.cache/upstart/gnome-keyring-ssh.log: There is no such file or folder
> ureadahead:/home/$USER/.cache/upstart/dbus.log: There is no such file or folder 
> and more ...
> ```

Deleting `/var/lib/ureadahead/pack` file/s (in order to rebuilding database) has no effect.

Ubuntu `15.10`, ureadahead `0.100.0-19`

Answer (score 4):

ureadahead is basically useless these days; even ubuntu has given up on it as of cosmic.  Just 'apt purge ureadahead" and get on with life.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo ureadahead --force-trace` might fix this

Everything has to be regenerated wich will remove nonexistent files